# How to pass credentials to use ResourceManagementClient to get all resources from azure resource group c#?

Tags: c#, azure, azure-resource-manager

I have install nuget `Microsoft.Azure.Management.ResourceManager` and have following code to get all existing resources based on `Resource Group Name`

```
 var resouceManagementClient = new ResourceManagementClient(credentials) { SubscriptionId = "mySubscriptionId" };

            var listResources =
            resouceManagementClient.ResourceGroups.ListResources("Demo-ResourceGroup");
```

I'm not sure from where I can get `credentials` parameter value.

> I do not have Azure Active Directory access , I think its must , can
>   we bypass azure AD?.

In my azure portal I have `create a Resource Group - Demo-ResourceGroup`
and have `many resources created`.

I want only list of all existing resources using c# code.

Answer (score 1):

One way is by grabbing an access token from Azure AD and passing it in to a `TokenCredentials` class.

```
var authContext = new AuthenticationContext(string.Format("https://login.windows.net/{0}", tenantId));
var credential = new ClientCredential(applicationId, password);
AuthenticationResult token = authContext.AcquireTokenAsync("https://management.core.windows.net/", credential).Result;
var credentials = new TokenCredentials(token.AccessToken);
```

The set of credentials you use to request the acces token (in this case clientId/secret) will determine whether the application has the appropriate rights to enumerate the resources. [This is a good MS docs page on how to register your application with AAD](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/active-directory/develop/active-directory-integrating-applications). In the example above, applicationId and password come from the application registration in AAD

[Microsoft has a page describing other ways you can get tokens from AAD](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/active-directory/develop/active-directory-authentication-scenarios).

Comment: what if I do not have permission to azure AD? any way to use `ResourceManagementClient`  without azure AD?

Comment: No you would need access to the Resource Group in order to enumerate the contents. Access is provided through the Active Directory associated with the subscription where the RG is hosted https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/active-directory/role-based-access-control-configure